# my code is not doing what it should as far as healing and damaging a enemy

Tags: gdscript, godot4

So I'm following along a zenva academy godot course are making micro turn based rpg and my heal and damage setup isn't doing things as intended. For whatever reason, when I click heal, it makes 25/25 go to 1/25.

As for damage, it just one-shots the enemy, even though the value should be 5 damage to one of the array options.

Here is the following scripts Character.gd

```
extends Node2D

class_name Character

@export var is_player : bool
@export var cur_hp : int = 25
@export var max_hp : int = 25 

@export var combat_actions : Array
@export var opponent : Node

@onready var health_bar : ProgressBar = get_node("HealthBar")
@onready var health_text : Label = get_node("HealthBar/HealthText")

@export var visual : Texture2D
@export var flip_visual : bool

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    $Sprite.texture = visual
    $Sprite.flip_h = flip_visual
    
    get_node("/root/BattleScene").character_begin_turn.connect(_on_character_begin_turn)
    health_bar.max_value = max_hp

func take_damage(damage):
    cur_hp -= damage
    _update_health_bar()
    
    if cur_hp <= 0:
        get_node("/root/BattleScene").character_died(self)
        queue_free()
    
func heal(amount):
    cur_hp += amount
    
    if cur_hp > max_hp:
        cur_hp = max_hp
    
    _update_health_bar()
    
    
func _update_health_bar ():
    health_bar.value = cur_hp
    health_text.text = str(cur_hp, " / ", max_hp)

func _on_character_begin_turn (character):
    if character == self and is_player == false:
        _decide_combat_action()

func cast_combat_action (action):
    if action.damage > 0:
        opponent.take_damage(action.damage)
    elif action.heal > 0:
        heal(action.heal)
        
    get_node("/root/BattleScene").end_current_turn()
    
func _decide_combat_action ():
    var health_percent = float(cur_hp) / float(max_hp)
    
    for i in combat_actions:
        var action = i as CombatAction
        
        if action.heal > 0:
            if randf() > health_percent + 0.2:
                cast_combat_action(action)
                return
            else:
                continue
        else:
            cast_combat_action(action)
            return
```

next is combatAction.gd

```
extends Resource
class_name CombatAction

@export var display_name = "Action (x DMG)"
@export var damage : int = 0
@export var heal : int = 0
```

here is CombatActionButton

```
extends Button

var combat_action : CombatAction

func _on_pressed():
    get_node("/root/BattleScene").cur_char.cast_combat_action(combat_action)

next is PlayerUi.gd

extends VBoxContainer

@export var buttons : Array

func _ready():
    get_node("/root/BattleScene").character_begin_turn.connect(_on_character_begin_turn)
    get_node("/root/BattleScene").character_end_turn.connect(_on_character_end_turn)
    
func _on_character_begin_turn (character):
    visible = character.is_player
    
    if character.is_player:
        _display_combat_actions(character.combat_actions)
    
func _on_character_end_turn (character):
    visible = false


func _display_combat_actions (combat_actions):
    for i in len(buttons):
        var button = get_node(buttons[i])
        
        if i < len(combat_actions):
            button.visible = true
            button.text = combat_actions[i].display_name
            button.combat_action = combat_actions[i]
        else:
            button.visible = false
```

And finally TurnManager.gd

```
extends Node

@export var player_char : Node
@export var enemy_char : Node
var cur_char : Character

@export var next_turn_delay : float = 1.0

var game_over : bool = false

signal character_begin_turn(character)
signal character_end_turn(character)

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    await get_tree().create_timer(0.5).timeout
    begin_next_turn()

func begin_next_turn():
    if cur_char == player_char:
        cur_char = enemy_char
    elif cur_char == enemy_char:
        cur_char = player_char
    else:
        cur_char = player_char
        
    emit_signal("character_begin_turn", cur_char)
    
func end_current_turn():
    emit_signal("character_end_turn", cur_char)
    
    await get_tree().create_timer(next_turn_delay).timeout
    
    if game_over == false:
        begin_next_turn()
    
func character_died (character):
    game_over = true
    
    if character.is_player == true:
        print("Game Over")
    else:
        print("You Win")
```

Any advice or feed back would be appreciated.

I double-checked for any errors on my part, but couldn't find anything. What I was expecting was heal to heal the player, not set the current hp to 1 and expect damage to damage the enemy by 5 not one-shot the enemy.

Comment: CombatActionButton is supposed to another gd script

Comment: Be aware that you can edit your own questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Reading the code is not giving me any clues of what is going on. I'm going to suggest to use breakpoints or prints to figure out if the values being passed around are what you expect.

Comment: Thanks you for the assistance the print made me want to check t the inspector and I found I didn't set the current hp which is what cause the code to mess up.